# Azure Runbook New-ADUser failing with permission denied even though domain admin

Tags: azure, runbook

Hey guys new to runbooks, but i am setting one up to add users to my on premise server. i already have a hybrid worker setup and is working best i can tell. when i run New-ADUser i get the standard permision denied even though i am using my domain admin account(just for testing).

The error seems the exact same as if i had tried to run the command from powershell, but not ran as administrator. im thinking this is the issue and i am just to new to know how to fix that, or if this is by design.

[91mNew-ADUser: [91mAccess is denied[0m

Comment: Hello @James Wright, Do you have installed [Ad modules](https://www.varonis.com/blog/powershell-active-directory-module#:~:text=On%20the%20Features%20page%2C%20expand,install%20completes%20successfully%2C%20click%20Close.) And make sure to run your PowerShell as an administrator.

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT I do have the Remot active directory modules installed. I also have the hybrid worker group permissions set to use shared credentials, which are my domain admin credentials for testing.

Comment: I didnt delegate control over the users OU, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt delegate control over the users OU, that was the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).